# How to determine ES version of a module

Tags: ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

The [Testing React Native Apps](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization) section of jest docs says,

> The transformIgnorePatterns option can be used to whitelist or blacklist files from being transformed with Babel. Many react-native npm modules unfortunately don't pre-compile their source code before publishing.

Lets say I add a new npm module(say **X**) to my project.

Now, I would now like to know if this(**X**) module is precompiled to maybe ES5 version, or is it still exported as a es6/es7/typescript module.

This will help me to figure out if I need to whitelist/blacklist the(**X**) module from being transformed.

**Is there a way to find out the ES version of a exported module?**

Answer (score 0):

I think, [this NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-check) is exactly what you need :)